# Requiring user-installed packages from byte-compiled .emacs

Tags: package, byte-compilation, require

I have the following in my `.emacs.el`:

```
(when (require 'edit-server nil t)
  (custom-set-variables
   '(edit-server-default-major-mode 'markdown-mode)
   '(edit-server-new-frame nil))
  (edit-server-start))
```

The file is byte compiled, so what is actually loaded is `.emacs.elc`.

`edit-server` is installed using the package system (`package-list-packages`).

When I start Emacs,

- `edit-server` is **not** running
- `(featurep 'edit-server)` is `nil`
- the variables are **not** set.

When I open `.emacs.el` and evaluate the `when` form, the server *is* started.

When I load `.emacs.elc` from `dired` right after starting emacs, the server *is* started.

When I start `emacs -q`, no matter how many times I load `.emacs.elc`, the server is not started.

So, why can't I start the server this way?

Comment: @Drew: I edited the answers to your questions into the question itself.

Comment: My `.emacs.el` as 1.5kloc. This is why I compile it.

Comment: Yes, same problem with a separate file.

Comment: thanks @Drew, I will. Thanks for pushing me to investigate further!

Answer (score 1):

Experiments revealed that byte-compilation was a red herring - it did not affect the behavior.

It turned out that I [**must** have `(package-initialize)` **before** `require`ing any packages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Package-Installation.html).